# UnitTest routerfunction

Tags: mockito, spring-webflux, project-reactor, java-11

i'm doing a unit test of handler(routerFunction) however it not executing.

handler:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReactiveAccommodationHandler implements 
AccommodationHandler {

private final ReactiveAccommodationService service;
private final PageResolver pageResolver;
private final WebMapper mapper;
private final ValidatorManager validator;

@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ACQUISITION_MANAGER')")
public Mono<ServerResponse> updateInternal(final ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    final Mono<PutAccommodationRequest> mono = serverRequest
        .bodyToMono(AccommodationResource.class)
        .map(resource -> mapper.dtoInPut(resource, serverRequest.pathVariable("accommodationId")))
        .doOnNext(request -> validator.validate(request));

    return noContent()
        .build(service.updateInternal(mono));
}}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccommodationHandlerTest {

@Mock
private ReactiveAccommodationService service;

@Mock
private PageResolver pageResolver;

@Mock
private WebMapper mapper;

@Mock
private ValidatorManager validator;

@InjectMocks
private ReactiveAccommodationHandler handler;

@Test
public void updateInternal() {
    //given
    final Long accommodationId = RandomUtils.nextLong();

    final AccommodationResource accommodation = AccommodationResource
        .builder()
        .accommodationId(accommodationId)
        .build();

    final Mono<AccommodationResource> accommodationMono = Mono.just(accommodation);

    final String accommodationIdAsString = accommodationId.toString();

    final PutAccommodationRequest request = PutAccommodationRequest
        .builder()
        .accommodationId(accommodationId)
        .build();


    final ServerRequest serverRequest = MockServerRequest
        .builder()
        .pathVariable("accommodationId", accommodationIdAsString)
        .body(accommodationMono);

    //when
    when(mapper.dtoInPut(eq(accommodation), eq(accommodationIdAsString))).thenReturn(request);
    doNothing().when(validator).validate(request);
    when(service.updateInternal(any(Mono.class))).thenReturn(Mono.empty());

    final Mono<ServerResponse> monoOut = handler.updateInternal(serverRequest);

    //then
    StepVerifier
        .create(monoOut)
        .expectNextMatches(response -> HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.equals(response.statusCode()))
        .expectComplete()
        .verify();

    verify(mapper).dtoInPut(eq(accommodation), eq(accommodationIdAsString));
}}
```

the source looks fine, however, when i run it, the verify complains about it:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mapper.dtoInPut(
AccommodationResource(accommodationId=6745422589255220224, name=null, 
type=null, billingData=null),
"6745422589255220224"
);
```

Any help would be appreciative.

aditional, this accommodation:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
@Wither
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class AccommodationResource {

@JsonProperty("id")
private final Long accommodationId;

private final String name;
private final Type type;

@JsonCreator
public AccommodationResource(
    @JsonProperty("id") final Long accommodationId,
    @JsonProperty("name") final String name,
    @JsonProperty("type") final Type type
{
    this.accommodationId = accommodationId;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}

public enum Type {

    APARTMENT,
    APARTHOTEL,
    BED_AND_BREAKFAST,
    COUNTRY_HOUSE,
    GUEST_HOUSE,
    FARM_STAY,
    LODGE,
    HOLIDAY_HOME,
    VILLA,
    HOTEL,
    HOSTEL,
    MOTEL,
    RESORT

}
}
```

Comment: Have you equals and hashcode in AccomodationResource?

Comment: no, only this lombok annotations Getter, Builder, ToString, Wither
and this for jackson JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

Comment: Is the `resource` in the lambda expression in `updateInternal` a `AccommodationResource`or a `Mono<AccommodationResource>`?

Comment: the handler receive a AccommodationResource, then convert into PutAccommodationRequest, and send Mono<PutAccommodationRequest> to service.updateInternal(...)

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that your problem is here:

Test:

```
final ServerRequest serverRequest = MockServerRequest
    .builder()
    .pathVariable("accommodationId", accommodationIdAsString)
    .body(accommodationMono);

final Mono<ServerResponse> monoOut = handler.updateInternal(serverRequest);
```

source:

```
final Mono<PutAccommodationRequest> mono = serverRequest
    .bodyToMono(AccommodationResource.class)
    .map(resource -> mapper.dtoInPut(resource, serverRequest.pathVariable("accommodationId")))
    .doOnNext(request -> validator.validate(request));

return noContent()
    .build(service.updateInternal(mono));
```

Something here is weird.

`service.updateInternal` takes a `Mono<PutAccommodationRequest>` in the source, but in your test it takes a `ServerRequest serverRequest`.

I find that a bit odd...

Comment: if you check the api, will that interface HandlerFunction accepts a ServerRequest and returns a ServerResponse. what happend inside method is other thing.

Comment: Why are you then passing a mono to it?